# taking array and building stream expressions in tcl

Tags: arrays, string, stream, tcl

I am trying to build a STREAM expression from the following array. the issue is, I want to copy particular strings from the array value and place repeat them at another place in the entire string. here is my code, and the desired outcome.

desired outcome:  STREAM::expression @$val-1@$val-2$val-1@@$val-3@$val-4$val-3@
original string:  $val-2$val-1$val-4$val-3
basically, val-1 represents a short string that i want to replace with a second string appended to it. another way to do an insertion in other words.

```
array set {
  key1 $val-2$val-1$val-4$val-3
}
```

i have code that puts the @ symbols, i just need to move the strings around.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem exactly. Is `val-1` for instance a string or a variable? If it is a string, I think that [this single RE](http://regex101.com/r/vR8nM1/1) could do both the shifting around and insertion of `@`, applied as `regsub -all {(\$val-\d+)(\$val-\d+)} $original_string {@\2@\1\2@} result_string`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this processing on a string value (that it is held in an array shouldn't be important), namely *without* regular expressions and *with* regular expressions.

### Without REs

```
set s {$val-2$val-1$val-4$val-3}
set substring [string range $s 6 12]
set s $substring$s
```

OK, there are a few ways to get the substring (e.g., an appropriate `split` and then `lindex`, as below) but it's hard to say what they would be without knowing the details.

```
set s {$val-2$val-1$val-4$val-3}
set bits [split $s {$}]
set substring \$[lindex $bits 2]
set s $substring$s
```

### With REs

```
set s {$val-2$val-1$val-4$val-3}
regsub {^.*?(\$val-1)} $s {\1&} s
```

In this case, you'll need to worry about the pattern to choose the piece you want. Basically the same problem as above, except now with REs. That might or might not make it easier…

---

All solutions above store exactly the following in the `s` variable:

```
$val-1$val-2$val-1$val-4$val-3
```

Comment: Thanks. I think option 2 shows much promise.  is there a way after getting the split, to look into an index for a string, like lindex $bits 2 contains "sometext".   each string may vary in number of items, is there a length parameter

Comment: @user1660886 Umm… maybe? I don't really understand the question.